# ANN: keras/sklearn doesn't scale well

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I don't know the reason why the results I have obtained aren't scale well.
As you can see on the pictures bellow, there is a problem with scaling.

[image]

[image]

There are two issues:

- There are no negative values
- There is problem with maximum values prediction

I don't have idea why I have those problems.
Do you have any idea's how I can fix this issue?

I would be very grateful for your help

CODE:

```python
# Read inputs
X = dataset.iloc[0:20000, [1, 4, 10]].values
# Read output
y = dataset.iloc[0:20000, 5].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Output matrix conversion
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

y_train = sc.fit_transform(y_train) 
y_test = sc.transform(y_test)

# Import the Keras libraries and package
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# building model
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", input_dim=3, units=64, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=32, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=16, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=1, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the training set
results = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=25)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. This question is about a classification problem rather than a programming problem. You might have more success at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kirk Good catch. Try `[so]` ([so]) sometime! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your blue curves show your initial output `y` and your orange ones the output of your model (you have not cared to clarify this...), then there is nothing strange here...

> There is problem with maximum values prediction

Looking more carefully at your code, you will realize that you don't actually feed your initial `y` into your network, but its *scaled* version, i.e. the result of `sc.transform()`; hence, your output is also scaled, and you should use the [`inverse_transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform) method to get it back to the initial scale:

```python
y_final = sc.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

BTW, this will happen to work now, but in general it is not a good idea to use the same scaler (`sc` here) for two different datasets (i.e. your X's and y's) - you should define two different scalers instead, say `sc_X` and `sc_y`.

> There are no negative values

That is because the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) you have used as activation in your output layer takes only positive values in [0, 1], so you may want to change it to something else that will be able to give the required value range (`linear` is a candidate), and possibly also change your other sigmoids to `tanh`.